# Change zoom level search in Geocoder folium

Tags: python, folium, geocoder

I have a folium map created in Python to which I added a search bar with the following code

```
Geocoder(add_marker=False).add_to(m)
```

When I search with this seach bar, the zoom is always the same, which is ok for city level, but if I want to see a street, for example, in more detail, it would be better if the map zoomed in a bit more.